# Multiple planes not visible during rendering

Tags: rendering, error

I am pretty new to blender so apologies in advance if this is a quick fix. I have created a book with animated pages. Each page is an individual plane with an image on both sides. I only needed the first 17 pages to animate, so the rest of the book is faked using a solid with page textures added to the sides etc. All animates fine and is visible in the viewport. However, when I come to render the animation, only the fake book solid is visible, none of the pages show up. I have gone through basic trouble shooting, but nothing works. Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Hard to tell wothout your settings and or blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Just an aside (not to solve your problem) but a 4096 sample size is *huge*; I normally use a max of 128 or so, for performance reasons.